# Why is arraylist still empty when when it should be populated with JSON data

Tags: android, json, arraylist

Im populating item object via data from JSON in AsyncTask and adding it to ArrayList. I execute JSON class in onCreate method of activity after which I print out size of ArrayList which is 0. Print of data in JSON class onPostExecute method is good so data is coming from web service like it should. Why is ArrayList still empty after JSONParse execution?

Sorry if I overlooked something elementary, I've just started learning andorid.

```
public class StaggeredGridActivity extends Activity implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener, AbsListView.OnItemClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = "StaggeredGridActivity";
    public static final String SAVED_DATA_KEY = "SAVED_DATA";

    private StaggeredGridView mGridView;
    private boolean mHasRequestedMore;
    private SampleAdapter mAdapter;

    //JSON FIELDS SETUP

    //URL
    String url = "http://.../web_services/get_items_test.php";

    //JSON Node Names
    private static final String TAG_ARRAY = "items";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_ITEMNAME = "iname";
    private static final String TAG_NEWPRICE = "new_price";
    private static final String TAG_STORENAME = "store_name";
    private static final String TAG_CURR = "curr";

    //JSON ARRAY
    JSONArray items = null;

    //ITEMS LIST
    ArrayList<Item> item_list = new ArrayList<Item>();



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sgv);

        //Execute JSON
        new JSONParse().execute();

        //PRINTS OUT 0!
        System.out.println(item_list.size());
        setTitle("SGV");
        mGridView = (StaggeredGridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);

        //LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();

        //View header = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_header_footer, null);
        //View footer = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_header_footer, null);
        //TextView txtHeaderTitle = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.txt_title);
        //TextView txtFooterTitle =  (TextView) footer.findViewById(R.id.txt_title);
        //txtHeaderTitle.setText("THE HEADER!");
        //txtFooterTitle.setText("THE FOOTER!");

        //mGridView.addHeaderView(header);
        //mGridView.addFooterView(footer);
        mAdapter = new SampleAdapter(this, R.id.txt_line1, item_list);

        // do we have saved data?
        /*if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mData = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList(SAVED_DATA_KEY);
        }
        */
        //if (mData == null) {
        //    mData = SampleData.generateSampleData();
        //}
        //    
        //for (String data : mData) {
        //mAdapter.add(data);
        //}

        mGridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        /*mGridView.setOnScrollListener(this);
        mGridView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        mGridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);*/
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_sgv_dynamic, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.col1:
                mGridView.setColumnCount(1);
                break;
            case R.id.col2:
                mGridView.setColumnCount(2);
                break;
            case R.id.col3:
                mGridView.setColumnCount(3);
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /*@Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(final Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putStringArrayList(SAVED_DATA_KEY, item_list);
    }
   */
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(final AbsListView view, final int scrollState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onScrollStateChanged:" + scrollState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(final AbsListView view, final int firstVisibleItem, final int visibleItemCount, final int totalItemCount) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onScroll firstVisibleItem:" + firstVisibleItem +
                            " visibleItemCount:" + visibleItemCount +
                            " totalItemCount:" + totalItemCount);
        // our handling
        if (!mHasRequestedMore) {
            int lastInScreen = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
            if (lastInScreen >= totalItemCount) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onScroll lastInScreen - so load more");
                mHasRequestedMore = true;
               // onLoadMoreItems();
            }
        }
    }
    /*private void onLoadMoreItems() {
        final ArrayList<Item> item = JSONParse.execute();
        for (String data : sampleData) {
            mAdapter.add(data);
        }
        // stash all the data in our backing store
        mData.addAll(sampleData);
        // notify the adapter that we can update now
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mHasRequestedMore = false;
    }*/

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Item Clicked: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Item Long Clicked: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

    /*****************************************JSON********************************************/
    //GET JSON DATA FROM URL 
    private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

        JSONparser jParser = new JSONparser();
        private JSONObject json;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

            // Getting JSON from URL
            json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
            return json;

        }

        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {

            try {
                 // Getting JSON Array from URL
                 items = json.getJSONArray(TAG_ARRAY);

                 for(int i = 0; i < items.length(); i++){

                     JSONObject c = items.getJSONObject(i);

                     // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
                     String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                     String itemname = c.getString(TAG_ITEMNAME);
                     String newprice = c.getString(TAG_NEWPRICE);
                     String storename = c.getString(TAG_STORENAME);
                     String curr = c.getString(TAG_CURR);

                     Item item = new Item();

                     item.setItemId(id);
                     item.setItemName(itemname);
                     item.setItemPrice(newprice);
                     item.setStoreName(storename);
                     item.setItemCurrency(curr);

                     item_list.add(item);

                     //This is good! It prints out all item names
                     System.out.println(item_list.get(i).getItemName());

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take all code in onCreate after the line `new JSONParse.execute()` and put it in a function. Call that function in onPostExecute().

Comment: Thx, it works. Is the reason for this execution in the background like Hades mentioned?

Comment: Yes. You have to wait until the list is filled in doInBackground. And then in onPostExecute handle the list. After the call to execute() immediately the next line will be executed but that is before the download is ready.

Answer (score 1):

`new JSONParse().execute();`  - is done in the background therefore when it executes `System.out.println(item_list.size());` in your `oncreate` method, the data has still not been downloaded...use the onPostExecute to update your view after the data has been downloaded...that is load your adapter...you need to understand why you're doing it in an AsyncTask.

Something to this effect,

```
 @Override
            public void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {

                try {
                     // Getting JSON Array from URL
                     items = json.getJSONArray(TAG_ARRAY);

                     for(int i = 0; i < items.length(); i++){

                         JSONObject c = items.getJSONObject(i);

                         // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
                         String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                         String itemname = c.getString(TAG_ITEMNAME);
                         String newprice = c.getString(TAG_NEWPRICE);
                         String storename = c.getString(TAG_STORENAME);
                         String curr = c.getString(TAG_CURR);

                         Item item = new Item();

                         item.setItemId(id);
                         item.setItemName(itemname);
                         item.setItemPrice(newprice);
                         item.setStoreName(storename);
                         item.setItemCurrency(curr);

                         item_list.add(item);

                         //This is good! It prints out all item names
                         System.out.println(item_list.get(i).getItemName());
                    }

                     mAdapter = new SampleAdapter(this, R.id.txt_line1, item_list);

                     for (Item data : item_list) {
                         mAdapter.add(data);
                     }

                     mGridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: Thx on your answer to Hades. You helped a lot with mAdapter.add(data) peace of code. GridView wasnt being populated without that part of the code. I assumed that it is enough to pass item_list to SampleAdapter constructor. I would appreciate if you could explain to me why just passing item_list is not enough?

Comment: think of the adapter as the bridge between the data and the view..so you need to add the data to the adapter, for it to work in the view...

Answer (score 0):

Query is still being executed and the results are not ready when you print them out. 
Have the `onPostExecute()` method for your AsyncTask. There you are sure that the query execution is finished and can call a function containing all your codes in that `onCreate()` method.